# SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, module, socket.io, syntax-error

I'm importing `import { io } from "./socket.io-client";` at the top of `app.js`, but I get this error `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`. I have a `script` tag under `body` like this:

`<script src="app.js"></script>`

What should I do to fix the error?

Comment: Do you have any other imports in your `app.js`?

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type

Comment: No. @zr0gravity7

Answer (score 3):

```html
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Then I get this error `Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/socket.io-client” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

Comment: You should make sure that the path is correct. Is it `socket.io-client.js` ?