# Saving mongo data to csv,json,excel etc with js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database, mongodb

I have a script which suppose to pull data from mongo and save data in JSON, CSV or EXCELL sheet. Currently, i am able to get data but during saving i am using the following
script.

```
   import fs from "fs"
    
    const cursor = db.getCollection("users").find({}, { name: 1,  email:1 , 
        phone:1});
    
    let users = [];
    
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
      const user = cursor.next();
      users.push({name: user.name, email:user.email, phone:user.phone})
     
    }
    
    //print(JSON.stringify(users))
    
    fs.writeFile ("test.json", JSON.stringify(users), function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('complete');
        }
    );
```

gives me this error

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at the top level of a module :
```

I have tried a couple of solutions from here [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237388/syntaxerror-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-module) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68271307/syntaxerror-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-module-how-t)

but non of them are working. Can anyone suggest me a solution

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing, getting same error

Comment: Hi, though I didn’t get what I wanted i did a workaround since I needed the output of that query so ran the query on terminal and passed those result in file

eg:
mongo db_name --quiet --eval 'DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 2000; db.users.find({}).limit(2000).toArray()' > users.json